# wordpress enhanced media library queried images not appearing with polylang

Tags: php, wordpress, internationalization, wordpress-theming, polylang

In my wordpress site, basically i have these two pages "gallery" and "galerija" (translated) that output some text and image gallery bellow.

I used enhanced media library so i could tag my images with a category and query just the images from that specific category called "image-gallery", and the code in `page-gallery.php` looks like this.

```
<?php
$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'attachment',
    'post_status' => 'any',
    'posts_per_page' => - 1,
    'tax_query' => array(
        array(
            'oderby' => 'title',
            'order' => 'ASC',
            'field' => 'slug',
            'taxonomy' => 'media_category',
            'terms' => 'image-gallery'
        )
    )
);

$query = new WP_Query($args);

while ($query->have_posts()):
    $query->the_post();
    $image = wp_get_attachment_image_src(get_the_ID() , 'full');
    echo "<img src='" . $image[0] . "'/>";
endwhile;
?>
```

The english page is working fine but the translated version with polylang doesn't display any images at all with the same query. I properly created a duplicate translated page like with my all other pages, shouldn't the same query work? i mean i just want images with the that specific term?

On some other post i have seen a suggestion that i should uncheck the option in language tab for `media` where it says: `Activate languages and translations for media` but that didn't work also.

Apparently my media library is empty because it says English (65) which are all images and for Serbian it says (0).
My knowledge of wordpress and php in general is bad though so i hope this makes sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

lol i came back several days later to check this again and apparently i just needed to go to the "language" tab for polylang and then "Custom post types and Taxonomies" and uncheck media categories.

"media" should be deactivated also by the way.